Using Fully Qualified Domain Names (FQDNs) for Service IDs in Kubernetes with Spring Cloud Kubernetes
I'm currently working on a project where I need to interact with services that have the same name but exist across different namespaces in Kubernetes. Each namespace hosts a service with a unique REST endpoint, necessitating the use of Fully Qualified Domain Names (FQDNs) to differentiate them. Here’s an example of what I'm dealing with:
http://account-integration-service.default.svc.cluster.local:8080
http://ccount-integration-service.welcoming.svc.cluster.local:8080
http://ccount-integration-service.sales.svc.cluster.local:8080
http://ccount-integration-service.aml.svc.cluster.local:8080

I'm exploring Spring Cloud Kubernetes for service discovery, but I'm encountering challenges when trying to configure it to use these FQDNs. Specifically, I've tried setting the serviceId to the FQDN format (account-integration-service.default.svc.cluster.local:8080) as per the Spring Cloud Kubernetes documentation(https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/reference/discovery-kubernetes-native.html), but I'm seeing errors indicating no servers are available for the service.
Here’s the configuration snippet I’ve used:
`serviceId: account-integration-service.default.svc.cluster.local:8080`

The logs show:
2024-07-17T13:52:50.764Z DEBUG [arrangement-manager,,] 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate : HTTP GET http://account-integration-service.default.svc.cluster.local:8080/service-api/v2/balances?arrangementIds=sara-curr-001&arrangementIds=sara-sav-002&arrangementIds=sara-sav-001
2024-07-17T13:52:50.768Z WARN [arrangement-manager,,] 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.c.l.core.RoundRobinLoadBalancer : No servers available for service: account-integration-service.default.svc.cluster.local
2024-07-17T13:52:50.769Z WARN [arrangement-manager,,] 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.c.l.core.RoundRobinLoadBalancer : No servers available for service: account-integration-service.default.svc.cluster.local

Has anyone successfully configured Spring Cloud Kubernetes to handle such scenarios with FQDNs across namespaces? Any insights or suggestions would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

yes, this should work. we even have integration tests in the project that test this. As with your previous question, a minimal, reproducible example, with clear instructions would help a lot in solving such issues.
